# Sorcery Log_out not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sorcery

Here is my route-

```
    get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
    post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
    delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
```

Here is my controller action-

```
  def destroy
    logout
    redirect_to(login_url, notice: 'You have Succesfully Logged out.')
  end
```

Here is my view-

```
  <li>
      <%if current_user %>
      <%= link_to logout_path, method: :delete do %>
      <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log out
      <%end%>
      <%end%>
  </li>
```

The problem I am having is: whenever I logout it says-

> No route matches [GET] "/logout".

I tried with `GET`, I tried with `DELETE` and `POST`, nothing works.

Routes

```
login_path  GET     /login(.:format)    sessions#new
            POST    /login(.:format)    sessions#create
logout_path DELETE  /logout(.:format)   sessions#destroy
```

Comment: Could you show the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: Updated With rake routes

Comment: Are you 100% you've tried `DELETE /logout`?

Comment: Yeah i did. You can see it on top view.

Comment: have you include  `jquery-ui` in the `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`?

Comment: Awesome.  That Fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have these in your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks.